# Google Earth plugin in webGL

Tags: 3d, webgl, google-earth-plugin

I have a web application done with google-earth-api and would like to extend this app, but I am really afraid to do this. Because nowadays, does not seem to make any sense to keep a plugin like Google Earth. Now we have webGl option as a new approach. Chrome experience is great example: chromeexperiments.com.

My question.

I know the question might be too generic but before getting down to study deeply I would like to hearing from you. I have not heard nothing about a version of GE Plugin in webGl technology.

Is there a GE Plugin webGl coming through in a near future?

Comment: There was a discussion in 27/02/2012 here.
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/1mJakRsi708
Any news so far.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is now a new approach available:  the AtomJump 3D Earth API is pure javascript,  without even needing Webgl.  This means you can safely add an interactive Earth to any Web page.

http://atomjump.com/earth.php

Comment: Well, I will take a look carefully, but it does not look like have the same power than google earth API. Load 3D stuff? KML? 3D view controllers? Google Earth API is a bit more cutting edge. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: This was designed to be widely browser-compatible at this stage (IE7 upwards, all major desktop browsers, iPhone, iPad, Android), so it is a base release. You can expect developments.  What are your application requirements?

Comment: I do really like to see these initiatives. But my APP is basically loading 3D stuff and 3D interactives view. The need to use a plugin is a shame.

Comment: Indeed, the AtomJump API might be able to meet your needs shortly based off what you describe - I suggest contacting AtomJump direct and having a discussion.

Comment: Hi, so AtomJump now supports KML and GeoJSON as well as different icons for each marker, and retina displays. There is a note on the FAQ about 3D loading/zooming coming.

Answer (score 1):

Forget Google and go for https://cesiumjs.org/index.html. It's trustful because it's open source, this way you avoid a Google dependency and problems like this: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html

Go for open source and if you don't trust Cesium project just fork it.